# How can I continue my program after writing to a text file in python?

Tags: python

```
import random

def findAccount():
    component1 = open('SampleData2017.txt','r')
    component2 = component1.readlines()

    accountOne = component2[0].split(',')
    accountTwo = component2[1].split(',')
    accountThree = component2[2].split(',')
    accountFour = component2[3].split(',')
    accountFive = component2[4].split(',')
    accountSix = component2[5].split(',')
    accountSeven = component2[6].split(',')
    accountEight = component2[7].split(',')

menuOption = input("What is the account holders surname?>  ")

if menuOption == "Griffiths":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountOne[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountOne[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountOne[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountOne[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountOne[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountOne[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Smith":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountTwo[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountTwo[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountTwo[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountTwo[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountTwo[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountTwo[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Miah":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountThree[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountThree[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountThree[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountThree[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountThree[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountThree[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Allen":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountFour[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountFour[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountFour[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountFour[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountFour[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountFour[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Hugget":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountFive[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountFive[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountFive[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountFive[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountFive[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountFive[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Selby":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountSix[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountSix[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountSix[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountSix[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountSix[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountSix[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Santus":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountSeven[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountSeven[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountSeven[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountSeven[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountSeven[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountSeven[5])
    menus()
elif menuOption == "Leewah":
    print ("Account ID:              ",accountEight[0],
           "\nAccount holder:        ",accountEight[1],
           "\nYear opened:             ",accountEight[2],
           "\nMembership status:   ",accountEight[3],
           "\nNo. of nights stayed: ",accountEight[4],
           "\nAmount of points:     ",accountEight[5])
    menus()
else:
    findAccount()

component1.close()

def menus():
    endOption = input("Do you want to continue?, press Y or N>  ")
    if endOption == "Y":
        menu()
    elif endOption == "N":
        exit()
    else:
        menus()


def addAccount():
    component2 = open('SampleData2017.txt','a')
    component4 = input("What is your name?>  ")
    component5 = str(input("What are the last two digits of the current 
year?>  "))
    component9 = str(input("What is the year?>  "))
    component6 = str(random.randint(1,999))
    component3 = component2.write(component4)
    component3 = component2.write(component6)
    component3 = component2.write(component5)
    component8 = component2.write(',')
    component8 = component2.write(component4)
    component8 = component2.write(',')
    component10 = component2.write(component9)
    component11 = component2.write(',')
    component12 = component2.write("Silver")
    component13 = component2.write(',')
    component14 = component2.write("0")
    component15 = component2.write(',')
    component16 = component2.write("0\n")
    print("\n\n")
    menus()

def menu():
    choice = input("What is thy bidding?\nEnter either Find Account or Add 
Account>  \n\n")
if choice == "Find Account":
    findAccount()
elif choice == "Add Account":
    addAccount()   
else:
    menu()

menu()
```

This is my VERY inefficient code.
Sorry.
Anyways, in the function addAccount(), it adds to the text file a new account but if you try and loop the program, it does not, I have tried using a function called menus() to make a discreet loop however it refuses to print to the ext file unless the program ends. Here is the text file:

Gri33415,Griffiths,2015,Gold,35,40000
Smi22316,Smith,2016,Silver,3,7500
Mia56213,Miah,2013,Platinum,140,165000
All78915,Allen,2015,Platinum,120,145000
Hug91714,Huggett,2014,Platinum,150,50000
Sel77617,Selby,2017,Gold,40,45000
San55614,Santus,2014,Silver,12,30000
Lee44213,Leewah,2013,Silver,15,37500

Any help would be great, I'm pretty bad at coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the call to menu at the end of the function, not in the else section:

```
def menu():
    choice = input("What is thy bidding?\nEnter either Find Account or Add 
Account>  \n\n")
    if choice == "Find Account":
        findAccount()
    elif choice == "Add Account":
        addAccount()   
    menu()
```

Anyway, you shouldn't do this as it will result in a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` in the long time. Better use a loop:

```
   def menu():
        continue = True
        while (continue):
            choice = input("What is thy bidding?\nEnter either Find Account or Add 
    Account>  \n\n")
            if choice == "Find Account":
                findAccount()
            elif choice == "Add Account":
                addAccount()   
            # Update continue if you need to stop
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    def menu():
        choice = input("What is thy bidding?\nEnter either Find Account or Add Account>  \n\n")
        if choice == "Find Account":
            findAccount()
        elif choice == "Add Account":
            addAccount()   

    while True:
        menu()
```

Watch out :-) `while True` means endless. You will have to interrupt this with `<ctrl>+c`